Why My Flutter app is not correctly running in the release mode, it is working fine in both profile and release mode?
My app is a fork of open source FileX App, which is also hosted on the Playstore and working fine in the release mode for android App.
github link of my project
In the release mode it is not fetching Recent Files. Image, video, Audio etc are also not working in release mode but in debug mode and profile everything is working nicely.
I'll request you to give it a try.
Tried in Profile mode and release mode.
Expecting to also work in the release mode too.
Tried following
flutter run -v --use-application-binary=build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk

Found that it was complaining of missing of "CoreProvider". I read somewhere in stackoverflow and used @pragma('vm:entry-point') over CoreProvider.
Now, it is giving me this error.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used
on a null value
[   +3 ms] E/flutter (16024): #0      FlutterIsolate._isolateInitialize.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_isolate/flutter_isolate.dart:141)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (16024): #1      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594)
[        ] E/flutter (16024): #2      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339)
[        ] E/flutter (16024): #3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271)
[        ] E/flutter (16024): #4      _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:784)
[        ] E/flutter (16024): #5      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:658)
[        ] E/flutter (16024): #6      _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:606)
[        ] E/flutter (16024): #7      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184)
[        ] E/flutter (16024): 

Since, the error is not in debug mode or profile mode but in release mode, I am facing difficulty to resolving it.

I have had similar problems when  woriking on a native android app, at that time the problem was the ofuscate that is only done when creating a release apk ... I would suggest you try with that, try to deactivate and check if it solves the problem, if it does and you still want to ofuscate, then you will have to solve the problem with proguard.
